# Python pandas, Iterate through a data frame rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to iterate through rows of a dataframe, I have read this datafarame from an Excel file, and it has 3 columns, I tried to get data of each row and convert it to a dict then store it in a list.

Dict format: `{"subreddit_group": string, "links/caption": list, "Subreddits/flair": list}`

my code:

```
data_list = []
linkcap_list = []
subredditflair_list = []
grp = ""
data = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["subreddit_group", "links/caption", "subreddits/flair"])
data_raw = {}
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    grp = row["subreddit_group"]
    elms = row['links/caption'].split(",,")
    for elm in elms:
        elm_linkcap = {}
        try:
            link, cap = elm.split("^")
            elm_linkcap = {"link": link, "caption": cap}
            linkcap_list.append(elm_linkcap)
        except ValueError as e:
            elm_linkcap = {"link": elm, "caption": "none"}
            linkcap_list.append(elm_linkcap)
    elms = row['subreddits/flair'].split(",")
    for elm in elms:
        elm_subredditflair = {}
        try:
            subreddit, flair = elm.split("^")
            elm_subredditflair = {"subreddit": subreddit, "flair": flair}
            subredditflair_list.append(elm_subredditflair)
        except ValueError as e:
            elm_subredditflair = {"subreddit": elm, "flair": "none"}
            subredditflair_list.append(elm_subredditflair)
    data_raw = {"group": grp, "links_caps": linkcap_list, "subreddits_flairs": subredditflair_list}
    data_list.append(data_raw)
```

I want to get the value of that column in each row, but every time I iterate through a row I get the value of the whole column I tried adding an index after the column name to access a specific cell, but I get a weird result, like this for example:

```
row['links/caption'][1]
```

how to iterate through a dataframe rows and access the value of each column, not the value of the whole column, I hope I was clear enough with my question, Thanks.
edit1:
using tuples.

```
data_list = []
linkcap_list = []
subredditflair_list = []
grp = ""
data = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx")
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["subreddit_group", "links/caption", "subreddits/flair"])
data_raw = {}
for row in df.itertuples():
    print(row)
    grp = row[1]
    elms_linkscaps = row[2].split(",,")
    elms_subredditsflairs = row[3].split(",")
    print(elms_subredditsflairs)
    print(elms_linkscaps)
    exit()
    for elm in elms_linkscaps:
        elm_linkcap = {}
        try:
            link, cap = elm.split("^")
            elm_linkcap = {"link": link, "caption": cap}
            linkcap_list.append(elm_linkcap)
        except ValueError as e:
            elm_linkcap = {"link": elm, "caption": "none"}
            linkcap_list.append(elm_linkcap)
    for elm in elms_subredditsflairs:
        elm_subredditflair = {}
        try:
            subreddit, flair = elm.split("^")
            elm_subredditflair = {"subreddit": subreddit, "flair": flair}
            subredditflair_list.append(elm_subredditflair)
        except ValueError as e:
            elm_subredditflair = {"subreddit": elm, "flair": "none"}
            subredditflair_list.append(elm_subredditflair)
    data_raw = {"group": grp, "links_caps": linkcap_list, "subreddits_flairs": subredditflair_list}
    data_list.append(data_raw)
```

Comment: `iterrows()` returns each row as a series. Use `itertuples()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I still get the same issue,

Comment: You shouldn't get the value of the whole column. `row` should be a series with just one row, not all the rows.

Comment: Yes, It returns a tuple instead I give it the index of 1 to get first column and so on, but I still get the whole column data, I think it is a logic error perhaps, although my code seems clear.

Comment: What do you mean by "get the whole column data"? You're looping through all the rows and appending them to your lists, so you get the whole column data that way.

Comment: I am iterating through  rows I access the first row data by row['links/caption'] or row[2].split(",,") if using itertuples(), I expect to get the data associated  with that row instead I get the data of the whole column on the first iteration.